# Completeness of $\{\sin nx \}$ over $(0, \pi)$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

This is stated as a miscellaneous theorem in the book 'Trigonometric series' by Zygmund.

Can anyone prove it? It is of use in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Have you tried using Stone-Weiertrass Theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Start with $f \in L^2[0,\pi]$, and extend $f$ to an odd function $f_o$ on $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$. Now expand $f_o$ in a Fourier series on $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$. The resulting Fourier sin series converges in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ to $f_o$ and, hence, also converges in $L^2[0,\pi]$ to $f$.

Comment: This is very smart. But somehow I still feel it is less intuitive.

Comment: @pe : You have odd and even basis elements in the classical trigonometric expansion on $[-\pi,\pi]$. That's where these arguments originated.